# Creating a Column in Dataframe by slicing a string in the DF with start and end position from the integers in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a dataframe which has strings  in a column  and integers in another  2 columns. Now I need to create a new  column which is a slicing of the string with start and end postion form the integer columns

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['hello', 0, 2],
    ['world', 1, 3],
], columns=['string', 'start', 'end'])
mapper = lambda r: r.string[r.start:r.end]
df['sliced_string'] = df.apply(mapper, axis=1)axis=1)
print(df)
```

produces

```
  string  start  end sliced_string
0  hello      0    2            he
1  world      1    3            or
```